# Find the chat both persons are a part of

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
chat_person
---
id chat_id person_id
1   1      20
2   1      19
3   2      19
4   2      3
5   3      19
6   3      2
```

I am trying to find the chat_id where p1=20 and p2=2 are both in. If there are none, return none.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "t1".chat_id
FROM "chat_person" t1
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM "chat_person" t2
        WHERE "t2".person_id = 20
    )
    AND "t1".person_id = 2
```

This query is incorrectly returning `chat_id: 3`. There is no common chat_id with both person_id=20 and person_id=2, so it should not return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have missed to add where condition in exist.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT "t1".chat_id
FROM "chat_person" t1
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM "chat_person" t2
        WHERE "t2".person_id = 20 and t2.ChatID = "t1".chat_id  
    )
    AND "t1".person_id = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

The most simple way is aggregation:

```
select chat_id
from chat_person
group by chat_id
having bool_or(person_id = 2) and bool_or(person_id = 20);
```

Comment: @Thorston Just wanted to know is  there any way like `sum(person_id)=22 and count(*)=2` in having to compensate person_id

Comment: @Himanshu Ahuja: Yes. Here are two options: (1) `having sum(when person_id in (2,22)) then 1 else 0 end) = 2`. (2) `where person_id in (2,22) group by chat_id having count(*) = 2`.

Comment: Perfect but second `where` statement  should not work in all cases as the Op's query says 20,2 can be there with other values as well Thanks mate :)

Comment: @imanshu Ahuja: The second statement works very well. We use `WHERE` to only get rows with persons 2 and 20. Then we see whether we get them both (`count(*) = 2`). Only if there could be duplicates in the table (which wouldn't make sense), we'd have to `count(distinct person_id)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT chat_id, count(distinct 
person_id) from table 
group by chat_id having 
  count(case when person_id in (2,20)
 then person_id end)=2
```

Comment: Yeah it could have been an error if the groups were to not fall in place as i guess groups are falling in place meaning 1 group 1 count, 2nd group 2nd count

Comment: Now it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

you could try like below if you need all the others fields

```
select t1.* from chat_person t1
 where exists ( select 1 from chat_person t2 where t2.chat_id=t1.chat_id
                                and person_id in (2,20)
                               having count(distinct person_id)=2)
```

or you can simply do like below if you just need `chat_id`

```
   select chat_id from cte t2 where 
   person_id in (2,20)
   group by chat_id
   having count(distinct person_id)=2
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9f8e27e38989b480dc138182ead1c595)